# this.someprop is undefined in constructor?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var PLAYER_INIT_ROW = 6;
var PLAYER_INIT_COL = 3;

var Player  = function(){
    this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
    var row = PLAYER_INIT_ROW;
    var col = PLAYER_INIT_COL;

    log("row:"+row);
    log("this.row:"+this.row);
    log("this:"+this);

    var coord = getCoord(row,col);
    var x = coord.x;
    var y = coord.y;

};

var player = new Player();
```

and the log:

> ```
> row:  6
> this.row:  undefined
> this:  [object Object]
> ```

and chrome debugger:

```
Local
col:3
coord:undefined
row:6
this:Player
    sprite:"images/char-boy.png"
    __proto__:Object
x:undefined
y:undefined
```

so, 'this' is exist but this.row is undefined. I guess when the constructing complete, this.row will be defined, isn't it?

Comment: Defined `var row` and using `this.row`. To add `row` on instance, define it as `this.row = PLAYER_INIT_ROW;` similar for `col`.

Comment: Thank you @Tushar, Since your help I found that `var row` is not a instance's prop, it's just a variable in the constructor..